# Set lastmodifieddate and/or createddate of a document when uploading with the REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest

I am making a rest call for inserting a document

Can someone please suggest how to set the lastmodifieddate and/or createddate of a document when uploading with the REST API

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to set these values something other than the actual created or last modified date which will automatically be set when you do the insert?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask salesforce support.  The special perm you need is called "Create Audit Fields"

Comment: This permission is not available for document object https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm#topic-title

Comment: Benjamin, you no longer need to ask SFDC to enable this permission